# Swift: How to return a dictionary in swift

Tags: swift, firebase

i want to return a dictionary but not could not get it work. I am calling a firebase fetch function

```
func fetch(childpath:String) -> NSDictionary {
    let firebaseUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let path = childpath.replacingOccurrences(of: "uid", with: firebaseUID!)
    var result = [:] as NSDictionary
  

    var children = [String]()
    var childrenPath = path.split(separator: "/")
 
    let childref  = ref.child("\(childrenPath[0])").child("\(childrenPath[1])")
        
        childref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
      // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

     
        result = value!
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
       
    }
    return result
    
    
}
```

I am calling the function above with this

```
 var FirebaseVal = FirebaseManager().fetch(childpath: "customers/uid")
```

I want FirebaseVal to be the dictionary returned in fetch() but all I am getting is empty. The value is displayed inside the function but not at FirebaseVal.
How can I get it to return a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `result` inside your `fetch(childpath:)` method is set asynchronously, you cannot use `return` in this case - you'll always return nil because the value is not set "on the fly".

What you should do is pass a closure as the second parameter to this method and call it when you wish to notify of the method's completion. Try this:

```swift
func fetch(childpath:String, completion: @escaping (NSDictionary?) -> Void) {
    let firebaseUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let path = childpath.replacingOccurrences(of: "uid", with: firebaseUID!)
        
    var children = [String]()
    var childrenPath = path.split(separator: "/")
        
    let childref = ref.child("\(childrenPath[0])").child("\(childrenPath[1])")
    childref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        completion(value)
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

And now you use the method like this:

```swift
FirebaseManager().fetch(childpath: "customers/uid") { result in
    if let result = result {
        // use your dictionary
    }
}
```